# How can I use Datatable in SpringBoot Server project?

Tags: spring-boot, datatable

I want use Datatable (plugin from jQuery) on my web application Server in Spring-Boot with maven.
This is my index.html:

```
<table id="myDataTable" class="dataTable display compact">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>                                        
            <th>Birthdate</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

but I'm not secure working effectively with datatable.
How can I express my intention to use datatable in my application? I must be download or import in pom.xml anything?

Comment: check this out: https://medium.com/@gustavo.ponce.ch/spring-boot-jquery-datatables-a2e816e2b5e9

Comment: well, I hope it's fine, thank you.